# Bind error even with setReuseAddress(true)

Tags: java, sockets

Maybe I misunderstand the use of this code, but from what I understand, calling setReuseAddress(true) will allow the port to be used even if the computer still thinks it is in use.

Scenario: I have the below code. When it crashes it does not close the port, so it throws a bind error on next launch. I have used setReuseAddress(true) to try to force it to open the port, but it throws the same error. If this is the right code, how do I use it? If it's the wrong code, what will allow this behavior?

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.Date;

public class ServerPsswd {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {


        ServerSocket listener = new ServerSocket();
        listener.setReuseAddress(true);
        listener.bind(new InetSocketAddress(9090));
        try {
            while (true) {
                Socket socket = listener.accept();
                try {
                    PrintWriter out =
                        new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
                    out.println("tada!");
                    out.println("yays");
                } finally {
                    socket.close();
                }
            }
        }
        finally {
            listener.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ah, the problem might in fact be that I was running 2 instances of it unwittingly

Answer (score 2):

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#setReuseAddress(boolean)

It is to allow connections during the timeout period AFTER the current connection has been closed

Comment: Ok, so this will be of no help on program crash then when the port is not closed at all. Is there a standard way of dealing with this?

Comment: It is designed for high volume ports where a few miilli/micro seconds count in every connection